# Which way to make this object class

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, class, object

I am creating a Character object that has an Inventory object. In the Inventory object you got a list of InventoryItem object and in every InventoryItem object you have an Item object.

Character <= Inventory <= Multiple inventoryItem <= Item

My problem is with the Item. An Item can be of multiple type. Every type got their own properties. So in my database I got thoses tables: Item, WeaponItem, ArmorItem, UseableItem, TrashItem, QuestItem and AccesoryItem. Every item type table got an ItemId to link them to the Item.

My question is: How do I implement the different type of item to my Item class?

What I thought about is making a Field/Property for each type and setting them all to null except the current type of the item. (Also maybe adding a table ItemType and adding it to the class Field/Property)

Another thing I thought about was making a class for each type and doing the same as above but with the objects themselves.

Would that be the good way to do it or is there better?

Here's my current Item class code:

```
public class Item
    {
        #region Fields
        //=======================================================================================
        private int itemId;
        private string itemName;
        private int itemLevel;
        private int itemRarityId;
        private int equipementSlotId;
        private int statsId;
        private Stats stats;
        private string imageUrl;
        private int equipementSlotSecondId;
        private int itemWeight;
        //=======================================================================================
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        //=======================================================================================
        public int ItemId
        {
            get
            {
                return itemId;
            }

            set
            {
                itemId = value;
            }
        }

        public string ItemName
        {
            get
            {
                return itemName;
            }
            set
            {
                itemName = value;
            }
        }

        public int ItemLevel
        {
            get
            {
                return itemLevel;
            }
            set
            {
                itemLevel = value;
            }
        }

        public int ItemRarityId
        {
            get
            {
                return itemRarityId;
            }
            set
            {
                itemRarityId = value;
            }
        }

        public int EquipementSlotId
        {
            get
            {
                return equipementSlotId;
            }
            set
            {
                equipementSlotId = value;
            }
        }

        public int StatsId
        {
            get
            {
                return statsId;
            }
            set
            {
                statsId = value;
            }
        }

        public Stats Stats
        {
            get
            {
                return stats;
            }
            set
            {
                stats = value;
            }
        }

        public string ImageUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return imageUrl;
            }
            set
            {
                imageUrl = value;
            }
        }

        public int EquipementSlotSecondId
        {
            get
            {
                return equipementSlotSecondId;
            }
            set
            {
                equipementSlotSecondId = value;
            }
        }

        public int ItemWeight
        {
            get
            {
                return itemWeight;
            }
            set
            {
                itemWeight = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        //=======================================================================================
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        //=======================================================================================
        public Item()
        {

        }

        public Item(int pItemId)
        {
            ItemId = pItemId;
        }
        //=======================================================================================
        #endregion
```

I can add any additional info if needed.

Edit: Inheritence. I'm stupid for forgetting about that.

So I make classes for each type that inherit my item class. Then my question change to this now:

When I create my character inventory with it's list of inventoryItem Item. To tell which item type class to use, do I have to create in my database an itemType property to my item or an ItemType table with every itemType then link it with an id then use this itemType/itemTypeId to tell which class to use? (Using a switch case) or did I get it wrong?

Sorry if the questions are a stupid, I'm a bit slow. :(

Comment: You need to learn inheritance.

Comment: Just a hint, in case you don't know: you can declare properties like this `public int ItemId { get; set; }`. It is a shorthand that works exactly like your properties, by creating a private field and accessing it in the `get` and `set` operators. That saves you a lot of typing.

Comment: Why do you have so many item tables? Do they have different properties? You don't show them in your code snippet. Can you share the table details?

Comment: @emd My brain is completly burned out right now and I just can't believe I forgot about that. D: To Wutz I just right click my Fields and encapsulate. Even faster. :p

Comment: @Tombala ArmorItem got and ArmorTypeId property, WeaponItem got WeaponTypeId, QuestItem got QuestId, AccesoryItem and Trash have nothing yet but I keep them separate for future changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comment above by emd, you can achieve this through inheritance. Create an abstract answer class from which you can derive the other classes.

```
// Base class from which all Item objects derive
public abstract class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
}

public class WeaponItem : Item
{
    // Add properties specific to WeaponItem here.
}

public class ArmorItem : Item
{
    // Add properties specific to ArmorItem here.
}
```

When using an Item object, you can check it's type like this:

```
WeaponItem weaponItem = item as WeaponItem;
If (weaponItem != null)
{
    // Do something relating to WeaponItem.
}
```

If loading from the database and assuming that you have an integer value that identifies the type of item:

```
switch (itemTypeId)
{
    case 1:
        new WeaponItem();
        break;
    case 2:
        new ArmorItem();
        break;
     // Others
}
```

Comment: Yep that's what I'm gonna do. I edited my question because I need clarification on something.

Comment: @snaplemouton - The easiest thing to do is to create an `enum` of types, with a value for each type, and store the `int` value of that enum as a field in the database.

Comment: If doing as @Bobson suggests, I would also add an abstract property to the base class, which when implemented in a derived class returns the value from the `enum` of types that corresponds to the derived type. Doing this would obviate the need to cast the Item object in order to determine its type.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very clear and easy to understand. :) I was trying to think too much and went completly lost.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a limited number of item types, I would avoid creating an item type table and keep things simple. In your inventory item, you would point to an Item.

```
public class InventoryItem
{
    public Item item { get; set; }
}
```

If you need to check for specific item types, you could have an enum or you could simply check for the concrete type:

```
if(inventoryItem.Item is ArmorItem)
{
    // Maybe you allow this item to be worn
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like @emd said, inheritance would be pretty useful in this case. You make your Item class the base class of the other classes you want to create (Weapon/Armor/etc).

Otherwise, another "cheaper" solution would be to add an enum for ItemType in this class. But if your other subclasses have too many properties, forget these last two lines and create some subclasses.